# Galilean Transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, symmetry, galilean-relativity

I tried to solve a problem using two different ways and I had some trouble, the problem is:

We define a symmetry transform of the expected value of $\vec{P}$ like this:
$$\langle \psi|\vec{P}|\psi \rangle \rightarrow \langle \psi|\vec{P}+m\vec{V_0}|\psi \rangle$$

being $\vec{V_0}$ a constant vector.

If we define the generators $\vec{K}$ like $$\vec{K}=-m \vec{T} $$
prove that we obtain the following relations.

$$ [K_j,P_k]=-im\delta_{jk} $$
$$ [K_j,K_k]=0 $$

**And my two solutions are**

Using $$U^-1 \vec{P} U = (1-i \vec{\epsilon} \vec{T}) \vec{P} (1+i \vec{\epsilon} \vec{T}) = \vec{P} + m\vec{V_0} = \vec{P} + \vec{\epsilon} $$ i end up with (where $\vec{\epsilon} \equiv m\vec{V_0} $)
$$ [\vec{K},\vec{P}] = -im $$
My problem is if we expand those vectors like this
$$ \vec{K}\vec{P}-\vec{P}\vec{K} = K_iP_i+K_jP_j+K_kP_k-K_iP_i-K_jP_j-K_kP_k = [K_i,P_i]+[K_j,P_j]+[K_k,P_k]=3[K_i,P_i] $$

and this gives $[K_i,P_i]=\frac{-im}{3} $ wich is wrong

But if I start with

$$(1-i \epsilon_i T_i) P_i (1+i \epsilon_i T_i) = P_i + m V_{i0} $$

we obtain the good answer

$$[K_i,P_i]=-im $$

so, my question is, whats wrong with the first method and why it doesn't give me the right answer.

Comment: Things like this $$ \vec{K}\vec{P}-\vec{P}\vec{K} = K_iP_i+K_jP_j+K_kP_k-K_iP_i-K_jP_j-K_kP_k $$ do not make sense. First of all you should try to clarify the meaning of notation to yourself.

Comment: Sorry i thought it was clear, its the dot product between two vectors, where $\vec{K}=(K_x,K_y,K_z)$ and $\vec{P}=(P_x,P_y,P_z)$, the result are the components, i should have wrote $K_xP_x+K_yP_y+K_zP_z -K_xP_x-K_yP_y-K_zP_z$

Comment: The point is that  $[\vec{A}, \vec{B}]$ does not make sense  within the formalism of QM. Just commutators of components $[A_i, B_j]$ make sense...

Comment: i see what you mean, you are right, but i could get the same expression i wrote from this expression
$i\vec{\epsilon} \vec{P} \vec{T}-i\vec{\epsilon} \vec{T} \vec{P} $, or not ?

Comment: Instead of starting from the ambiguous object (where is the dot product therein?)$$U^{-1} \vec{P} U = (1-i \vec{\epsilon} \vec{T}) \vec{P} (1+i \vec{\epsilon} \vec{T})$$ start from  $$U^{-1} P_k U = (1-i \sum_j\epsilon_j T_j)P_k (1+i  \sum_r\epsilon_r T_r)$$ and go on...